# How to generate method stubs automatically in VS 2008 or using Coderush Express?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Recently I implemented an interface which had some 130 members that i should implement (C#, but i think thats irrelevant).

How can i generate the stubs for all those automatically, in VS 2008

Edit:If its not possible in VS 2008, i've also installed Coderush Express, can some one guide me on how to do that with CR Express ?

Comment: See my answer - yes its possible "out of the box" using VS.NET 2008 Professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left click on the interface, select "implement interface."

```
public class Whatever : IXmlSerializable
```

You need to click near the "I" that has a little underline.

Also, other tools such as Resharper and DevExpress do it for you too.

Are you using VS.NET Professional?

Comment: If you're into keyboard shortcuts, place your cursor on the interface name in the class delcaration, and press Control+Period and then hit Enter :)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, if you click on the Interface you're implementing, you'll see a little menu option. Click on that and select "Implement Interface". This should produce all the stubs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class YourClassName : IComparable
```

You can also right click on the interface -->  Implement Interface --> Implement Interface.

Does the same as Kris and Tenaciouslmpy says.