# How do you auto-implement an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Previously in Visual Studio, if you declared a class with an interface you could put your cursor on the interface, right-click it and select **Implement Interface**. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095385/how-to-generate-method-stubs-automatically-in-vs-2008-or-using-coderush-express) for a similar question for VS 2008.)

I've started working on a project that has defined numerous interfaces that will be used with SimpleInjector.  Now, as I am beginning to write my service classes, I've noticed that the **Implement Interface** menu option is gone.

How can I implement all necessary method stubs like I could in VS 2008?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, however, I couldn't find this answer anywhere.

---

**EDIT NOTES - Aug 17, 2018**

This has been a hot question over the years. I've updated the title and tags for this so that it covers all pertinent versions of C# and Visual Studio.

This was ultimately a coder FAIL on my part.  Much like classes, interfaces when generated by VS aren't defined as `public`.  You will have to manually modify the interface declaration with the `public` accessor since VS doesn't automatically add it.  It's easy to forget this step because you don't have to set member modifiers within the interface since, by definition, they will all be `public`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1s9z1w.aspx it seems to be still there

Comment: FYI, this feature also exists in VS2010. I haven't actually _tried_ using it in VS2012 as I normally don't leverage that feature too often, so I can't comment if it's there or not. But in my experience, if you have other compile errors in your code at the same time, or missing relevant assembly references, sometimes options like that don't appear because it can't figure out what it is or what you're doing.

Comment: Works for me, as always. The "Implement interface" is the first menu item in the context menu available when you right click the interface name. VS2012 for sure.

Comment: I want to implement `IComparable` interface in 2010 VS and still doesn't show me the blue tag... Darn thing! When debug no errors either. What am I missing here? Found the issue. There are two types of interfaces. One for type-safe using Generics and the other for non-type safe. I had to use type-safe to see the blue tag. But I am doubtful, why is that so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That hasn't changed. All you need to do is hover over the interface name in the class, and the blue underline bar should show up, giving you options to implement the interface. If the blue underline is not appearing, check to make sure the interface is accessible with what assemblies and namespaces you are referencing.

Comment: Ah, fail on my part.  This was occurring due to a mistake I made when I defined the interface.  I wasn't getting any warnings from Intellisense.  I fixed the interface and the drop-down option from the interface declaration appeared.

Comment: @RLH: Can I take a guess? `public class IMyInterfaceIAccidentallyDeclaredAsAClass { }`?

Comment: Yup.  I always get the declaration skewed.  The interface must be defined as public, the methods have no public/private declaration.

Comment: The "blue line" may (VS 2013) appear under the class name (and not under the interface) but you can still right-click the Interface and choose implement - it works just the same

Answer (score 10):

When you look at the interface name, you should see a little blue underline:

[image: first image]

If you hover over it, a drop down menu will appear, letting you implement the interface:

[image: second image]

Answer (score 8):

Put your cursor somewhere in the interface text (the part after the colon) and hit <kbd>Ctrl + .</kbd>