# How do I get VS to implement a default method in ALL classes based on interface

Tags: c#, interface, interface-implementation

I have and interface with 5 mthods.

I want to add a 6th method, but I would like to avoid having to manually add the method to each claas I have that uses the interface.

Can I either:

1. Tell interface the class does NOT have to be implemented.
   OR
2. Have VS add empty method to each derived class automatically.

Is either of the above possible?

Comment: Use a class implementing the 6th method. Let all classes derive from it.

Comment: Create a new interface, add it to classes you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844122/how-do-you-auto-implement-an-interface-in-c-sharp-4-0-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Will all the classes that implement your interface have different implementations of that method? Do all the classes even require the method? Seems like a design issue if you do not want that method to be implemented in all classes, in this situation you want to extract this functionality to a separate interface which is only implemented on the classes that require it. Otherwise if you are going to implement them you'll have to go through each one manually and implement the interface (ctrl+.) when the cursor is on the interface of the class.

Comment: @Mukund - is there an implement interface ALL? - I have a lot of classes

Comment: put the cursor on interface name which you want to implement and then do 'ctrl+'. This will implement this interface in all the class which are implementing this.